# Docker Mounting Error - File Not Found

Tags: docker

I am trying to run the below Docker command but am receiving a file not found error.  I have verified that the local folder `/D/VMs/...` contains the appropriate file, and that the `adam-submit` command is properly functioning. I believe there is an issue with how I am mounting the local folder - I assumed that it would be at the location `/data`  for the docker machine. For context, I am following the tutorial at http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/5/exercises/genome-analysis-with-adam.html
using the docker image at https://hub.docker.com/r/heuermh/adam/

Docker Run:

`docker run -v '/D/VMs/hs/adam/data:/data' heuermh/adam adam-submit transform '/data/NA12878.sam' '/data/NA12878.adam'`

Docker Run #2:

`docker run -v //d/vms/hs/adam/data:/data heuermh/adam adam-submit transform /data/NA12878.sam /data/NA12878.adam`

Error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Couldn't find any files matching /data/NA12878.sam. If you are trying to glob a directory of Parquet files, you need to glob inside the directory as well (e.g., "glob.me.*.adam/*", instead of "glob.me.*.adam"`

Answer (score 0):

From the directories you listed, it looks like you're running Docker for Windows. This runs inside of a VM, and folders mapped into a container are mapped from that VM. To map a folder from the parent OS, it needs to first be shared to the VM which is enabled by default on C:/Users.

If you're using docker-machine, check the settings of your VirtualBox, otherwise, check the settings of Docker itself for sharing folders and make sure /D/VMs is included.

Comment: I am actually relying on Docker Toolbox, which I hope operates the same way as you described. However, I tried moving my `/data` folder to `C:/users` and running `docker run -v '/c/users/data:/data ...` but to no avail.

Comment: Users is case sensitive (this is a Linux based VM), so make sure you use Users and not users.